# What does ...のなんでやろ。 mean?　Is that a やる verb? is の a normalization particle? If so, what is なんで？

Tags: grammar, kansai-ben

Some Youtube comments:

> 1) 日本人にとっても日本語ってクソムズイのに、外国人に簡単だとか言われると腹立つ**のなんでやろ**。しかもカタコトでwww
>   誰もこのコメの意味分からんだろうけどさwww
>   2) 文化を知らずして日本語を喋る人は大体ただの糞外人

What does ...のなんでやろ。 mean?　Is that a やる verb? is の a normalization particle? If so, what is なんで？

Comment: Whole sentence would be nice. To get the context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

やろ (or やろう) is a Kansai equivalent of だろ(う) which means "I wonder" or "I think." This の is a nominalizer which nominalizes everything before it (日本人にとっても～腹立つ).

～の(は)なんでやろ = ～の(は)なぜだろう = I wonder why ～.